# LaTex equation out of page margin

Tags: equations, margins

I am a LaTex beginner and I am writing my first formal document using it.
I have to write a quite long equation, and it goes out of page bounds for some reason as I show here:

[image]

Here you are the code I run:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w) = (x+y+z+\bar{w}) * (x+y+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) * (x+\bar{y}+z+w) * (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) * (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) * (\bar{x}+y+z+w) * (\bar{x}+y+z+\bar{w}) * (\bar{x}+y+\bar{z}+w) * (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+z+\bar{w}) * (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) 
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

How can I solve this? Thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: Adding line breaks somewhere  (\\\)?

Comment: @Fran Can Is there a command to make it automatic? So that if I change something in the equation it will adjust automatically.

Comment: `split` *allows* splitting across lines, but does not do it: the author has to decide where to set the line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution....to split it....with edit by comment of the user.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w) & = (x+y+z+\bar{w})\cdot (x+y+\bar{z}+\bar{w})\cdot (x+\bar{y}+z+w) \\
&\cdot  (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) \cdot (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) \cdot (\bar{x}+y+z+w) \\
&\cdot (\bar{x}+y+z+\bar{w}) \cdot (\bar{x}+y+\bar{z}+w)\\
& \cdot (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+z+\bar{w}) \cdot  (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w)
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a little problem: in the last line, there should be a `\cdot` instead of a `=` but this is what I am looking for, thank you!

Comment: @EminentEmperorPenguin I'm happy to help you..can you see, please, if is it good now?

Comment: All good now. Thank you.

Comment: Please, can you check green mark to egreg? It is the best answer than mine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EminentEmperorPenguin There is yet, the green check mark...switch it to egreg. Thank you very much. After you choose any codes.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose an `autosplit` environment, but it's much better to split the big thing by hand as in the last example.

The optional argument to `autosplit` is the fraction of the display width to fill. The default is `0.9` (that is, 90%).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{autosplit}[2][0.9]
 {%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$#2{}$}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  $\displaystyle#2{}$%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr#1\displaywidth-\dimen0}
  %\raggedright
  $\displaystyle
 }
 {$\end{minipage}\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{autosplit}{f(x,y,z,w) =}
  (x+y+z+\bar{w}) \* (x+y+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) \* (x+\bar{y}+z+w) \* 
  (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) \* (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) \* (\bar{x}+y+z+w) \* 
  (\bar{x}+y+z+\bar{w}) \* (\bar{x}+y+\bar{z}+w) \* (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+z+\bar{w}) \* 
  (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) 
\end{autosplit}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{autosplit}[0.8]{f(x,y,z,w) =}
  (x+y+z+\bar{w}) \* (x+y+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) \* (x+\bar{y}+z+w) \* 
  (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) \* (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) \* (\bar{x}+y+z+w) \* 
  (\bar{x}+y+z+\bar{w}) \* (\bar{x}+y+\bar{z}+w) \* (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+z+\bar{w}) \* 
  (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) 
\end{autosplit}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x,y,z,w)={}&
  (x+y+z+\bar{w}) (x+y+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) (x+\bar{y}+z+w) \\
{}\cdot{}&
  (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) (x+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+\bar{w}) (\bar{x}+y+z+w) \\
{}\cdot{}&
  (\bar{x}+y+z+\bar{w}) (\bar{x}+y+\bar{z}+w) (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+z+\bar{w}) \\
{}\cdot{}&
  (\bar{x}+\bar{y}+\bar{z}+w) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `autosplit` is good but as I tried, I found the standard method clearer. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @EminentEmperorPenguin I mentioned it just to show the limitations with having TeX doing the breaks itself.